# 404 Not found while instantiating web worker in backbone.jsI

Tags: web, backbone.js, marionette, web-worker

I was trying to implement web worker in a backbone.js project and I got the error message **src/js/worker.js 404 (Not Found)**

I created a worker.js file and I have the code below in the file

```
this.addEventListner('message', function(e){
   console.log('Message received: ', e.data);
});
```

And the below code sends message to the worker

```
let worker = new Worker('src/js/worker.js')
worker.postMessage('hello');
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When you open your developer tools and look in the Network tab, does the requested URL match your expectations?

Comment: @Xufox, Yes the Request URL matched my expectations

Answer (score 1):

It appears, that you try loading ther service worker script from an insecure location. I recommend you serving you development pages from `http://localhost` to make your first steps with service workers. You will find a great "guidepost" at the ["Is ServiceWorker Ready?"](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/resources.html) web site.

Make sure, that you:

- Serve the page and the service worker script from a web server.
- Use the [HTTPS protocol with a valid TLS certificate](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https), or HTTP only with `localhost`.

You won't be able to load the service worker script from `http` or `https` protcols without a valid certificate. Serving you page from `http://localhost` is an exception; `localhost` is considered secure to make the development easier. See also [the full list of "secure" origins as implemented in Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features#TOC-Definitions-).

You will get the same error, if the file is missing or if the browser cannot load it from the protocol, which you used:

```
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
ServiceWorker registration failed:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker:
  A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

If the SSL certificate of your web site is invalid, including self-signed certificates, you will get the following error:

```
An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker:
  An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.
```

If you use a self-signed certificate, you can [install the SSL certificate of your "fake" CA as a trusted root certificate authority in your web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7580508/623816) or OS. The browser will not ask you for an exception in accessing your page any more and the service worker will load well.

If you use Chrome, you can use parameters `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and `--allow-insecure-localhost` to force the browser to [load the service worker script from otherwise illegal origins](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq). But do it only in your development environment. Not at the production web site.